# ddclient fails to update ip on namescheap.com

Tags: dynamic-dns, ubuntu-14.04, namecheap, ddclient

I'm using ddclient 3.8.1 on ubuntu 14.04 to update my dns records on namecheap.com. But now it stopped working. Syslog says:

```
WARNING:  file /tmp/ddclient.cache, line 3: Invalid Value for keyword 'ip' = ''
```

And when I run `ddclient -query` I get

```
use=web, web=http://whatismyipaddress.com/ address is NOT FOUND
```

My `/etc/ddclient.conf` is:

```
daemon=300
cache=/tmp/ddclient.cache
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid
ssl=yes
syslog=yes
use=web, web=http://whatismyipaddress.com/, web-skip='Your IP address is'              

protocol=namecheap
server=dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com
login=foo.bar
password='password'
my.foo.bar
```

I've tried to access http://whatismyipaddress.com and it is working just fine.

Comment: It's disappointing that a bunch of folks voted this as off-topic with respect to professional sys admin. It's entirely relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems whatismyipaddress.com is blocking scripts. You can try to use another IP-address lookup site. Change your `ddclient.conf` to contain:

```
use=web, web=http://ipinfo.io, web-skip='ip": "'
```

Should provide your public IP to ddclient.